# AngularJS - can you chain then() to previously resolved promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I looked at this post: [Can you resolve an angularjs promise before you return it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555472/can-a-you-resolve-an-angularjs-promise-before-you-return-it)

I'm trying to apply it to my code, and it seems to not be working.

Here's my code:

```
 var myPromise = $timeout(function () { ... }, 1000);

    myPromise.then(function () { ... }); // the code in here runs

    $timeout.flush(); // this causes the promise to become resolved and the code in the 1st then above to run.

    // I expect this code to run immediately, since the promise is already resolved - but it doesn't
    myPromise.then(function () { ... });
```

Note: this code is running inside a karma test function, so $timeout should work normally... unless it has issues with resolved promises?

Comment: $timeout does not support .flush. Check your console log for errors. It is supported in ngMock - is that what you are using?

Comment: Yes it does, it works in all my tests

Comment: Looks like it doesn't: http://plnkr.co/edit/sD4uCNrdMhh0Q8hQwLWp?p=preview (check the console)

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? Try adding a `$rootScope.$digest()` after the `.then` is added. Note that in regular non-unit test code it will just work

Comment: 1.3. Why should digest do anything? The 1st flush shouldv resolved the promise - and the flush works as expected for the 1st then, since it does get triggered

Comment: @GilMoshayof The promise is resolved, yes, but in general it's in fact the $digest loop that runs the result callbacks. $timeout.flush() also calls $digest, so the first run does get called. Add a $scope.$digest() after you add the second callback, and you should get the result you're expecting.

Comment: calling $digest worked. If you compose this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is $timeout.flush() method, it's available only in tests(see docs): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout
and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout

If you remove it -- everything works as expected.

Comment: Im checking this in a test, so it should work inside the test, shouldn't it?

Comment: Have you angular-mocks.js added to your html after angular.js?

Comment: Yes, our yeoman scaffolding manages this. Note that when i call flush, the 1st then is triggered, but the 2nd then i add afterwards does not get called (im assuming the flush resolved the timeout promise)

Comment: ok, I have no idea what is wrong there, but I assume that this is not related to promises, because it should be possible to call `then` on resolved promise and code will be executed: http://plnkr.co/edit/QzJGcMIvgjA1sr64jfVI?p=preview

Comment: I assume that this is related to ngMock $timeout implementation, and I can't really debug this now.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Ill try to alter my mocks so they use $q instead of timeout and see if my tests pass that way.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rytmis noted, calling $scope.digest worked. Here's the code now:

```
var myPromise = $timeout(function () { ... }, 1000);

    myPromise.then(function () { ... }); // the code in here runs

    $timeout.flush(); // this causes the promise to become resolved and the code in the 1st then above to run.

    // I expect this code to run immediately, since the promise is already resolved - but it doesn't
    myPromise.then(function () { ... }); 

    rootScope.$digest(); // This will trigger the 2nd promise.
```

As people here mentioned, were this code to run normally, it wouldn't need the digest call. The digest is only needed since this code is running from a test.