# AngularJS Bypass promise if data is present in cache

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am sending an ajax request to fetch data from server and storing it in local variable. This is inside service. Then in controller I am using the promise to get the data when needed. For the first time it works because the no cache is detected and promise is returned but next time onwards I am not returning any promise from the service function and hence javascript error.

My function in the service is:

```
    getProductDetails: function(product) {
        if(!productDetailsArr[product.id]) {
            if (!promiseProductDetails) {
                // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
                promiseProductDetails = $http.get(product.id + '/productdetails.json').then(function(response) {
                    productDetailsArr[product.id] = response;
                    return productDetailsArr[product.id];
                });
            }
            // Return the promise to the controller
            return promiseProductDetails;
        } else {
            return productDetailsArr[product.id];
        }

    }
```

In the controller I have invoked the above function with following code:

```
ServiceData.getProductDetails($scope.product).then(function(data) {
    $scope.productDetails = data;
});
```

So on second time onwards I get the JS error:

```
TypeError: ServiceData.getProductDetails(...).then is not a function
```

Any idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should be doing is always returning a promise. In this case, you can simply return an already resolved promise. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555472/can-you-resolve-an-angularjs-promise-before-you-return-it).

```
    if(!productDetailsArr[product.id]) {
        if (!promiseProductDetails) {
            // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
            promiseProductDetails = $http.get(product.id + '/productdetails.json').then(function(response) {
                productDetailsArr[product.id] = response;
                return productDetailsArr[product.id];
            });
        }
        // Return the promise to the controller
        return promiseProductDetails;
    } else {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(productDetailsArr[product.id]);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: else block could be shorter: `return $q.when(productDetailsArr[product.id]);`