# Angular Then doesn't trigger for Promise on Recursive Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

Just when I thought I had promises figured out, I'm stumped again.  I am trying to use a recursive function to return a promise.  It looks like it is working but the "then" portion never gets hit.  I tried using `$q.all` but that is causing me a problem with multiple calls to my Web API.  Rewriting the code to use recursion seemed like the answer, but I cannot get the "then" to execute.  I figure that I must be missing something simple but I can't seem to figure out just what.

Here is the call to the function:

```
                    getClusterLink(linkcodes, returnString)
                    .then(function () {
                        value.vchTextBeforeQuestionCluster = $scope.returnString;

                    })
```

Here is the recursive function:

```
    function getClusterLink(linkcodes, returnString) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $scope.returnString = returnString;
    if (linkcount < linkcodes.length) {
        contractorService.gethyperlink(linkcodes[linkcount])
        .success(function (data) {
            var vchUrl = data[0].vchUrl;
            var end = vchUrl.length;
            var docID = vchUrl.substring(vchUrl.indexOf("=") + 1, end);
            var vchLinkName = data[0].vchLinkName;
            var yay = '<a href="" ng-click="getDocumentByID(' + docID + ')">' + vchLinkName + '</a>';
            var yCode = "|Y" + linkcodes[linkcount] + "~";
            $scope.returnString = $scope.returnString.replaceAll(yCode, yay);
            linkcount++;

            return getClusterLink(linkcodes, $scope.returnString);
        })

    }
    else {
        deferred.resolve();
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
```

The function itself works correctly.  It hits the `resolve` and the `return deferred.promise`, but the "then" never fires.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't return anything in the first branch of the conditional...surprised you're not getting a type error.

Comment: I do.  I return the function.

Comment: Only `return` I see in that branch is *inside a callback*

Comment: there is a return in the if, and a return in the else.

Comment: Last chance for help. **THAT RETURN IS INSIDE AN INNER FUNCTION** (the one passed to the `success` method of whatever is returned by `contractorService.gethyperlink`). It will *not* return *anything* to the caller of `getClusterLink`. Either edit the question, or I'm flaging to close as a typographical error.

Comment: It is a recursive function.  If you don't understand recursion you won't be able to help.  The function works correctly the problem is returning the promise when it finishes.

Comment: @JaredSmith is correct. Your recursion logic is correct, hence it's working. However, the promise chain is broken because `getClusterLink` does not return anything in the first 'if' block. The `return getClusterLink(...` is relative to the anonymous function in your success callback. If the `contractorService.gethyperlink` service method is also a promise; perhaps try returning it?: `return contractorService.gethyperlink`.

Comment: I was using the recursive function to try to chain the async calls.  It seems that I can use "reduce" to accomplish what I am trying to do with the recursion.  I just have to figure out how to do.  Thanks for your help @Corey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Seems the problem was that I had `var deferred = $q.defer()` inside of the recursive function so it kept resetting the variable.  Moving it outside of the function (like below) resolved the issue and the "then" now fires.

```
   var thisdeferred = $q.defer();

function getClusterLink(linkcodes, returnString) {

    if (linkcount < linkcodes.length) {
        contractorService.gethyperlink(linkcodes[linkcount])
        .success(function (data) {
            var vchUrl = data[0].vchUrl;
            var end = vchUrl.length;
            var docID = vchUrl.substring(vchUrl.indexOf("=") + 1, end);
            var vchLinkName = data[0].vchLinkName;
            var yay = '<a href="" ng-click="getDocumentByID(' + docID + ')">' + vchLinkName + '</a>';
            var yCode = "|Y" + linkcodes[linkcount] + "~";
            $scope.returnString = $scope.returnString.replaceAll(yCode, yay);
            linkcount++;
            return getClusterLink(linkcodes, $scope.returnString);
        })


    }
    else {
        thisdeferred.resolve();
    }
    return thisdeferred.promise;

};
```

Answer (score 1):

promise has to be returned by the function before resolve or rejecting it.

```
function getClusterLink(linkcodes, returnString) {
var deferred = $q.defer();
$scope.returnString = returnString;
if (linkcount < linkcodes.length) {
    contractorService.gethyperlink(linkcodes[linkcount])
    .success(function (data) {
        var vchUrl = data[0].vchUrl;
        var end = vchUrl.length;
        var docID = vchUrl.substring(vchUrl.indexOf("=") + 1, end);
        var vchLinkName = data[0].vchLinkName;
        var yay = '<a href="" ng-click="getDocumentByID(' + docID + ')">' + vchLinkName + '</a>';
        var yCode = "|Y" + linkcodes[linkcount] + "~";
        $scope.returnString = $scope.returnString.replaceAll(yCode, yay);
        linkcount++;


    })
 return getClusterLink(linkcodes, $scope.returnString);
}
else {
    deferred.resolve();
}
return deferred.promise;
};
```

.then is implemented on promise object. So as the function is returning the promise ,.then would work fine.

You can look at this sample https://jsbin.com/daseyu/edit?html,js,console,output
It works fine.

I think the problem is because you are returning getClusterLink in success. You can return in end of if loop and not in .success.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried that first.  It doesn't work.  Also by putting outside of the if statement, it keeps returning the promise over and over no matter what.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Please note that I did not down vote your answer.  It did help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getClusterLink` function does not return a promise in the case where `contractorService.gethyperlink` is called. I wonder you don't get an exception from that. And even if you always returned `deferred.promise`, it wouldn't be resolved in that branch.

But you should not use a deferred at all here. [Just use `$q.resolve`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29750735/1048572), and chain onto the `$http` promise that `gethyperlink` returns. Notice that `.success` is deprecated, and does no chaining like `then` does - `return`ing from that callback is pointless.

```
function getClusterLink(linkcodes, returnString) {
    $scope.returnString = returnString;
    if (linkcount < linkcodes.length) {
        return contractorService.gethyperlink(linkcodes[linkcount])
//      ^^^^^^
        .then(function (data) {
//      ^^^^^
            var vchUrl = data[0].vchUrl;
            var end = vchUrl.length;
            var docID = vchUrl.substring(vchUrl.indexOf("=") + 1, end);
            var vchLinkName = data[0].vchLinkName;
            var yay = '<a href="" ng-click="getDocumentByID(' + docID + ')">' + vchLinkName + '</a>';
            var yCode = "|Y" + linkcodes[linkcount] + "~";
            $scope.returnString = $scope.returnString.replaceAll(yCode, yay);
            linkcount++;

            return getClusterLink(linkcodes, $scope.returnString);
        });
    } else {
        return $q.resolve();
    }
}
```